# zend framework wiki

Tags: zend-framework

Where is zend framework wiki? 
http://framework.zend.com/wiki/ : "An error occurred with this request: Invalid controller specified (wiki)."

googling gives nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zend Frameworks development tools are down for a couple of hours, because of a server relocation.

See [this tweet from @weierophinney](http://twitter.com/weierophinney/status/4370431047) :

```
#zf dev tools (tracker/svn/wiki) will be down for 12-15hrs starting 21:00 GMT for a server reloc. #zendframework
5:18 PM Sep 25th from Tweetie
```

I'm guessing it's taking a bit longer than what was initialy planned, as both [wiki](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV/Home), [issue tracker](http://framework.zend.com/issues), and [SVN access](http://framework.zend.com/code/browse/Zend_Framework) are still down.

---

**EDIT after the comment :** If you want to learn using Zend Framework, you can still take a look at :

- [ZF's QUickstart](http://framework.zend.com/docs/quickstart)
- The [Reference Guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/)
- Or the electronic book *(still work in progress, but the first chapters are great)* [Survive The Deep End!](http://www.survivethedeepend.com/)

---

**EDIT a couple of hours later :**

See [this second tweet from @weierophinney](http://twitter.com/weierophinney/status/4400416803), just a few minutes ago :

```
#zf SVN and developer tools are back up and running -- thanks everyone for your patience during our migration! #zendframework
8 minutes ago from web
```

And, indeed, wiki, issue tracker, and SVN are all back online !

Comment: oh, thank you very much!

i've just decided to spend some time to learn :)

Comment: @valya : you're welcome :-)  ;; I've edited my answer to post a few likns you can still use -- the wiki is not that much necessary when you want to learn Zend Framework, I'd say -- at least not to start :-) ;; Have fun !

Comment: Bad luck :-D I just tried again, clicking on the "wiki" link in my answer, and I'm sent to http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV/Home which looks OK ^^ Maybe some kind of DNS-propagation problem, or anything like that ?